# Populate ViewModel with multiple objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, repository

Considering this ViewModel

```
public class DocumentReferenceViewModel
{
    public int IdDocumentReference { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageNbr { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

- The DocumentTitle is a property of a **Document** object
- The **IdDocumentReference** and **PageNumber** are properties of
  DocumentReference object

**Document** and **DocumentReference** are linked with a propertie *IdDocument*

- I have a repository which can return **Document** objects
- I have a repository which can return **DocumentReference** objects

---

```
public class DocumentReference
{
    public int IdDocumentReference;
    public string PageNbr { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}


public class Document
{
    public int IdDocument;
    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
}
```

How can I bind the ViewModel from theses 2 objects (tables) without looping on the DocumentReference and for each one querying the database to retrieve de DocumentTitle ?

ps : I am not using EF, I have repositories calling handwritten Stored Procedures

Answer (score 0):

you can use constructors in your ViewModel:

```
public class DocumentReferenceViewModel
{
    public int IdDocumentReference { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
    public string PageNbr { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public DocumentReferenceViewModel(){}

    public DocumentReferenceViewModel(Document doc, DocumentReference docRef){

      this.DocumentTitle = doc.DocumentTitle;
      this.IdDocumentReference = docRef.IdDocumentReference;
      this.PageNbr = docRef.PageNbr ;
    }
}
```

Also You can Add Constructors with Comment Property.

```
public DocumentReferenceViewModel(Document doc, DocumentReference docRef, string comment){

      this.DocumentTitle = doc.DocumentTitle;
      this.IdDocumentReference = docRef.IdDocumentReference;
      this.PageNbr = docRef.PageNbr ;
      this.Comment = comment;
    }
```

The you get from the repository `Document` and `DocumentReference` and create an Instance with one of new constructors.

Comment: Thank you so I will had to loop over the reference, and for each reference query the database for the document Title. But I want to avoid that. I think that I can probably create a stored procedure which get all the information for each DocumentReference, but I do not have an elegant way to implement that

Comment: @Massanu You can Ask another question, this is completely another topic

Comment: If you re-read my question you will find that I had already precised that I used Stored procedures, and repositories and I am looking for a solution without looping and querying for each DocumentReference.